# console.log in express.js route not logging mongodb ._id field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I have a weird situation and I'm unable to figure out why. 
I'm learning MEAN and have the following setup:

My PUG file:

```
    br
  for product in products
    div.container
      div.row.border
        div.col-md-3
          p= product.name
          p= product._id
        div.col-md-3
          p= product.description
        div.col-md-3
          p= "$" + " " +product.price
        div.col-md-3
          form(action="/cart", method="post")
            input(type="hidden", value="#{product._id}" , name="id")
            button(type="Submit") Add To Cart
```

My index.js file (basic one just to display my documents and delete them)

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var cart = require('../lib/Cart.js');
var db = require('../lib/db.js');
var database = require('../database.js')

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Products = mongoose.model('Product');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

mongoose.connect = ('mongodb://localhost/products');


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // console.log(sayHelloEnglish());

    Products.find(function (err, products) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Express 2017 ', products: products });
        console.log(products);
    });
});


router.post('/', function (req, res) {
   // var newUser = new User ({name : req.body.name});
   // newUser.save(function(err, users){
     //   res.render('index', {title: "whatever"})
    //});

     var newProduct = new Products({ name: req.body.name, description: req.body.description, price: req.body.price });
    newProduct.save(function (err, products) {
        res.render('index', { title: "PRODUCTS", products: products });
    });
});

 //console.log is logging #{product._id} and not the value???
router.post('/cart', (function (req, res) {
    var id = req.body.id
    console.log(id);
    res.render('cart', {title: "Cart"});
}));

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the question:
My console.log result is

```
#{product._id}
```

It's not logging the actual id which is something like this: 5a0341e2ff549f2de8e307be
Any insight would be greatly appreciated as I'm unable to figure it out. 
why console.log is showing the @{product._id} and not the actual id value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style of attribute is no longer supported in pug:

```
 input(type="hidden", value="#{product._id}" , name="id")
```

use this instead:

```
 input(type="hidden", value=product._id , name="id")
```

More examples in the migration guide here: https://pugjs.org/api/migration-v2.html#attribute-interpolation

Comment: Thank you. Haven't used it in a while.